# SQL set operation for update latest record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am facing a problem and cant find any solution to this. I have a source table (T) where I get data from field. The data may contain duplicate records with time stamp. My objective is to take the field data and store it into a final table (F) having the same structure. 
Before inserting I check whether key field exists or not in the F if yes I update the the record in F with the latest one from T. Other wise I Insert the record in F from T. This works fine as long as there is no duplicate record in T. In case T has two records of the same key with different time stamp. It always inserts both the record (In case the key is primary key the insert operation fails). I am using following code for the operation -

```
         IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [Final_Table] F, TMP_Source T WHERE T.IKEy =F.IKEY)
                begin 
                    print 'Update'


                    UPDATE [Final_Table]
                    SET [FULLNAME] = T.FULLNAME
                    ,[FATHERNAME] = T.FATHERNAME
                    ,[MOTHERNAME] = T.MOTHERNAME
                    ,[SPOUSENAME] = T.SPOUSENAME

                    from TMP_Source T
                    WHERE Final_Table.IKEy = T.IKEy 
                        and [Final_Table].[RCRD_CRN_DATE] < T.RCRD_CRN_DATE
                    --Print 'Update'
                end
                               else
                begin

                    INSERT INTO [Final_Table]
                    ([IKEy],[FTIN],[FULLNAME],[FATHERNAME],[MOTHERNAME],[SPOUSENAME]
                    )
                    Select IKEy,FTIN,FULLNAME,FATHERNAME,MOTHERNAME,SPOUSENAME
                    from TMP_Source 

                end
```

The problem comes when I my T table has entries like -

```
   IKey RCRD_CRN_DATE ...
   123 10-11-2013-12.20.30
   123 10-11-2013-12.20.35
   345 10-11-2013-01.10.10
```

All three are inserted in the F table.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all but the latest row as a first step (well, in a [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)) using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) before attempting to perform the insert:

```
;WITH UniqueRows AS (
    SELECT IKey,RCRD_CRN_DATE,FULL_NAME,FATHER_NAME,MOTHER_NAME,SPOUSENAME,FTIN,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IKey ORDER BY RCRD_CRN_DATE desc) as rn
    FROM TMP_Source
)
MERGE INTO Final_Table t
USING (SELECT * FROM UniqueRows WHERE rn = 1) s
ON t.IKey = s.IKey
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
      SET [FULLNAME] = s.FULLNAME
         ,[FATHERNAME] = s.FATHERNAME
         ,[MOTHERNAME] = s.MOTHERNAME
         ,[SPOUSENAME] = s.SPOUSENAME
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
    ([IKEy],[FTIN],[FULLNAME],[FATHERNAME],[MOTHERNAME],[SPOUSENAME]) VALUES
    (s.IKEy,s.FTIN,s.FULLNAME,s.FATHERNAME,s.MOTHERNAME,s.SPOUSENAME);
```

(I may not have all the columns entirely correct, they seem to keep switching around in your question)

(As you may have noticed, I've also switched to using [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) since it allows us to express everything as a single declarative statement rather than writing procedural code)